# How to put .png image into head title

Tags: javascript, html

How do you put an image into your title. I don't mean the internet tab icon created using something like:

```
<link rel="icon" href="image.png">
```

I want to have another .png in my title. Something like:

```
<title>Website text <link rel="icon" href="image2.png"></title>
```

How do you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. [A `<title>` tag can't (validly) contain any other tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element). You could, however, use an emoticon (or any Unicode character) and get fairly decent cross-browser rendering, if there is an emoticon or other character that looks like the image you want to use.